# Having real trouble finding element on Selenium using python to scrape Instagram

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, instagram

I'm having a real hard time scraping Instagram, and tried everything and about to just give up, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but can't seem to grab the total followers on the page. I've tried the code supplied by other posts, but to no avail. I've tried using grabbing the element with driver.find_elements_by_class_name as well as xpath.
[image]

I've tried below individually (moving to next if first didn't work, not same time obviously)without any luck:

```
data  = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g47SYlOXF2")
data  = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g47SY lOXF2")
data  = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("g47SY.lOXF2")
```

Above returns a empty list each time.

I've also tried Xpath: followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath(followers_x), with followers_x being the following tries individually. Each time it can't find the element

```
followers_x ='//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a/span'
followers_x = '//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/ul/li[2]/a'
followers_x = '//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/article/header/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a/span'
followers_x = "//span[@id='react-root']//span[@title]"
followers_x = "//a[@span='g47SY lOXF2']"
followers_x = './/*[contains(text(), "followers")]/span'

followers = followers_x.get_attribute("title")
```

Each attempt gives me a selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException

I'm hard-up.... can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: try `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='Y8-fY '][2]/a/span").text`

Answer (score 0):

To get the title from followers you need to Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and following xpath.

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//a[contains(.,' followers')]/span"))).get_attribute('title'))
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```